# Convergence to zero of multiplicative function.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Let's say $f(n)$ is multiplicative function. Suppose that $f(p^m) \to 0$ as $p^m \to \infty$. Then is it true that $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

If it's true - it would be helpful in different type of tasks. I've just thought about it , while solving some problem. Any ideas?

Maybe it's better to divide $p_i$ (which used in prime representation) into some groups ?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of your limit assumption. It is ambiguous, see my comment below reuns' answer for details.

Comment: @Ingix The meaning you propose, the one of Jens answer, has trivial answer, why would you want to choose it ?

Comment: I do not want to choose anything, it's the OP's problem. And questions with 'trivial' answers abound on this site, it often just depends on your knowledge if a question is hard or trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $f$ is multiplicative and $f(p^m) \to 0$ as $p^m \to \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) =0$

Let $$h(n) = \sup_{p^m \| n} p^m $$ be the largest prime power dividing $n$, if $n > p^m!$ then $h(n) > p^m$ thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} h(n) = \infty$$
Let $$A =\prod_{p^m, |f(p^m)|> 1} |f(p^m)|, \qquad \forall n, |f(n)| \le A$$

then

$$|f(n)| = |f(\frac{n}{h(n)})| |f(h(n))|\le A |f(h(n))|, \qquad\lim_{p^m \to \infty} f(p^m)=0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=0$$

Comment: I don't understand your argument, but see the other answer.

Comment: @J.G. my bad! I've eddited

Comment: I think you are using an unintended interpretation of $f(p^m) \to \infty$ as $p^m \to \infty$. I'm 99.9% sure it's supposed to mean more formally $\forall p \in \mathbb Z, p > 0$ p prime we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}f(p^m) = 0$ if $m \to \infty$ ($m$ varies among positive integers). Or maybe you are right and the OP wanted your definition.

Comment: @Ingix At first the OP wrote as $ m \to \infty$ it is because we told him it was ridiculous that he changed. $p^m \to \infty$ means what it means.

Comment: Good, I didn't know that the question was changed. I'll look at your solution again.

Comment: Why $A$ should be finite?

Comment: @openspace Because the limit of $f(p^m)$ is zero when $p^m$ tends to $\infty$. So there must be a number $N$ with $f(p^m) \le 1 \forall p^m \ge N$.

Comment: @Ingix also does there product amond all powers of primes, or among all $m$ powers?

Comment: @openspace All prime powers. If you put them into an ordered sequnece, they look like (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16,17,19,23,25,27,29,...).

Comment: I don't see how Jens' counterexample below can be dismissed: $f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is the product of different primes to the first power, otherwise $f(n) = 0$. If $n=p_1p_2 \cdots p_k$ where the $p_i$ are all distinct and in ascending order, then $f(h(n)) = f(p_k) = 1$, which does not go to zero with $n$.

Comment: @MikeBertrand Your function is $|\mu(n)|$ then $\lim_{p\to \infty} |\mu(p)|= 1$ not $0$ so it doesn't satisfy the first line condition of my answer

Comment: I don't see the point when @reuns is writing "if $n>p^m!$ then $h(n)>p^m$''. How to control $h(n)$ ?

Comment: @P.Fazioli  $n$ is a product of finitely many and distinct prime powers, it cannot be larger than factorial $h(n)$.

Comment: Let $p_0$ be a prime number. I want to show that $\exists N / \forall n>N \; h(n)>p_0$. I have the feeling that you propose $N=p_0!$. In this case : let $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}>p_0!$. Then $h(n)=p_s^{\alpha_s}$...why should it be $>p_0$ ? Thank you.

Comment: @P.Fazioli $n$ is a product of distinct integers all $\le h(n)$ so it can't be $> h(n)!$

Comment: Your last comment awoke me, I am dumm. Sorry and many thanks @reuns.

Answer (score 3):

A multiplicative function $f$ is uniquely defined  by the values $f(p^m)$. So let $f(p):=1$ and $f(p^m):=0$ when $m>1$.  Then $ f$ satisfies the hypothesis but not the desired conclusion.

Comment: Or more generally, fix any $\epsilon>0$, then require $f(p)\ge\epsilon$ for all $p\in\Bbb P$. Then $f(n)\ge\epsilon$ for arbitrarily large prime choices of $n$.